# Freezer component not working in Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, screen-capture

https://github.com/haga-rak/Freezer

we are trying to capture a screenshot of a web page using Freezer component. everything seems working as expected locally, but when it is hosted in Azure Web API, the call is failing with below error

```
RemoteWorker has shutdown at Freezer.Pools.WorkerEngine.CaptureUrl(String baseUrl, TimeSpan timeOut) at Freezer.Engines.CaptureEngine.CaptureRawUrl(String baseUrl, TimeSpan timeOut) at Freezer.Core.ScreenshotHelper.FreezeTaskABytes(ScreenshotJob task) at Freezer.Core.ScreenshotJob.Freeze()
```